# Apache Kafka : "Attempt to join group xxxxxxxxxxx failed due to unknown member id" . Any thoughts on why this would occur

Tags: apache-kafka

Version : 0.9
Kafka consumer is throwing the below error message in the logs

**"Attempt to join group xxxxxxxxxxx failed due to unknown member id" . Any thoughts on why this would occur**

Running 3 consumers and only one consumer showing up when i run the kafka-consumer-groups.sh command for the consumer group.

Any thoughts on why this would occur ?

Consumer Properties:

```
        Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", config.getServerList());
        props.put("group.id", config.getGroupName());
        props.put("key.deserializer", config.getKeyDeSerilizar());
        props.put("value.deserializer", config.getValueDeSerilizar());
        props.put("fetch.wait.max.ms", "1000");
        props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(config.getEnableAutoCommit())) {
            props.put("enable.auto.commit", config.getEnableAutoCommit());
        } else {
            props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(config.getAutoCommitIntervalMillis())) {
            props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", config.getAutoCommitIntervalMillis());
        } else {
            props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        }

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(config.getAutoOffsetReset())) {
            props.put("auto.offset.reset", config.getAutoOffsetReset());
        } else {
            props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        }
```